# represending packet with char pointer in caller without allocation and allocating it in other function

Tags: c

I have this function. Basically what what I am doing is getting `char *` without initial call to `malloc` or assigned value. So can say its un- initialized pointer

```
        void abc(char **c)
        {
            *c=(char *) malloc(sizeof(struct ethhdr)+sizeof(struct iphdr)+sizeof(struct tcphdr)+1000/*1000=payload*/);
            struct ethhdr *eth=(struct ethhdr *)&*c;
            struct iphdr *ip=(struct iphdr *)(&*eth+sizeof(struct ethhdr));
            struct tcphdr *tcp=(struct tcphdr *)(&*ip+sizeof(struct iphdr));
            //populate eth
            //...
            //populate ip
            //...
            //populate tcp
            tcp->source=80;
            printf("%d\n",tcp->source);
            int *x=(int *)*c;
            //x=10;

        }

        void main(){
            char *pay;
            abc(&pay);
            struct ethhdr *eth=(struct ethhdr *)pay;
            struct iphdr *ip=(struct iphdr *)(eth+sizeof(struct ethhdr));
            struct tcphdr *tcp=(struct tcphdr *)(ip+sizeof(struct iphdr));
            printf("%d\n",tcp->source);
        }
```

What I want is to be able to call the function abc from main do allocation in `abc` that is sizeof network paacket including ethhdr+iphdr+tcphdr+1000=payload
And use the packet in main like printing what has been assigned in `abc function`

**Update**

the code above in `abc` causing segFault like when I 80 is assinged to port.

So question is how can I assign the value 80 to tcp port and get it printed in main. Please use my example

Comment: First off your code does not build.  Have you attempted a compile for the code you are showing? Please edit your post to include a [mcve].

Comment: On a side note, why are you engaging with this manual size calculation? Why not use a struct which has all the members in it, and allocate just this struct and access it's members using member access rather than by hand-calculated offset?

Comment: @SergeyA If I take the advice from the answer then what else could go wrong if I chooses this way'

Comment: Advice deals with how you change the interface to allocate space. I am talking about *what* you allocate.

Answer (score 2):

You have basically this situation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void abc(char* c)
{
  c = malloc(100);    // this modifies the local variable c
                      // BTW no cast is needed with malloc
  strcpy(c, "Hello World!");
}

void main()
{
  char* pay;
  abc(&pay);           // pay won't be modified by calling `abc`
  printf("%s\n", pay); // printing an uninitialized pointer top char
}                      // will most likely crash
```

But you want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void abc(char **c)    // ** double pointer here, c is a pointer to a pointer to char
{
  *c = malloc(100);
  strcpy(*c, "Hello World!");
}

void main()
{
  char* pay;
  abc(&pay);
  printf("%s\n", pay);
}
```

There may be more problems though.

Comment: `There may be more problems, especially sizeof(struct tcphdr+ 1000 /*1000=payload*/) looks very fishy.` what do u mean. I plan to send simple `html` header plus some html tags in the payload. if I adjust the size of `html` header plus some tags then what do u mean by `fishy`?

Comment: `There may be more problems though.` I am not gonna go and get segFault. please clarify

Comment: @666 is means that I didn't check thoroughly the code in `abc`. Especially the `//...` parts.

Comment: Basically I am creating server application. client request tcp connection. so in first received packet I will use received packet ethernet header source address(eth address) and memcpy to the out going packet destination ethernet address. same I will do in other source and destination addresses in ip header and tcp header ports. is this part correct or do I need to ask separate question?

Comment: please look at the question update its still not working in my example